# Redirect to root url In vaadin

Tags: web, vaadin, vaadin7

i have a simple Vaadin login application.After user login the URL looks something like below

> http://localhost:8080/app/#!loogedin

what i wanted to do is after logout the URL should look something like this

> http://localhost:8080/app/

i have tried

```
Page.getCurrent().setUriFragment("", true);
```

but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the redirect using the `setLocation()` method in `Page`. This needs to be done before closing the session, as the UI or page are not available after that.

```
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new Button("Logout", event -> {// Java 8
            // Redirect this page immediately
            getPage().setLocation("/myapp/logout.html");

            // Close the session
            getSession().close();
        }));

        // Notice quickly if other UIs are closed
        setPollInterval(3000);
    }
}
```

To understand further have a look [Closing a session](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.lifecycle.html)

Comment: Glad that it helped u... :)

Answer (score 0):

for vaadin 10, you may use this code instead

```
getUI().ifPresent(ui -> {
    ui.getPage().executeJavaScript("window.location.href = 'you url'");
});
```

reference
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17069258